# Number of ways to arrange 4 balls selected from a pail of 6 Red and 3 Green?

Tags: probability

You can select 4 balls each time and each arrangement must look different.

My way of solving it was simply writing down all possible arrangements, but none of them match the given choices of 15, 16, 10, 11 or 12. I got 13 possible different arrangements.

RRRR
RRRG
RRGR
RGRR
GRRR
RRGG
RGRG
GRGR
GGRR
RGGG
GRGG
GGRG
GGGR

Any hints?

Comment: What does it mean to "arrange" them?  If you just mean to put them in a line, then there would be $2^4=16$ except there aren't enough Greens to make $GGGG$ so the answer is $16-1=15$.

Comment: Note:  your list is missing $RGGR$ and $GRRG$.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed $GRRG$ and $RGGR$.

Answer (score 0):

You have 1 possibility for 0 green

you have 4 posibilities for 1 green $\frac{4!}{3!.1!}$

you have 6 posibilities for 2 green $\frac{4!}{2!.2!}$

you have 4 posibilities for 3 green $\frac{4!}{1!.3!}$

with the total of 15.

In general the number of combinations for $r$ red balls and $n-r$ green balls is $\frac{n!}{r!.(n-r)!}$ that is the combinatory number $C(n,r)$